# How to set an onClickListner on an expandable RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to make an application which fetches data from a local sqlite database and puts them in a recyclerview, The following image illustrates what I'm trying to do:[image]

The app is working fine except the part when you want to click on the category text link, e.g. drinks so that it will return all the items in the drinks category i.e. the 2 Mazowe items. The code is working only if you click on the circled - or + symbols and not when you press the text. Here is the code:

```
package com.vhg.empire.merchant.Account;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vhg.empire.merchant.Cart.AddCartItems;
import com.vhg.empire.merchant.R;
import com.vhg.empire.merchant.database.ProductDetailObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by VinceGee on 09/30/15.
 */
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
public static final int HEADER = 0;
public static final int CHILD = 1;

private List<Item> data;

public ExpandableListAdapter(List<Item> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
    View view = null;
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    float dp = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int subItemPaddingLeft = (int) (18 * dp);
    int subItemPaddingTopAndBottom = (int) (5 * dp);
    switch (type) {
        case HEADER:
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_header, parent, false);
            ListHeaderViewHolder header = new ListHeaderViewHolder(view);
            return header;
        case CHILD:
            TextView itemTextView = new TextView(context);
            itemTextView.setPadding(subItemPaddingLeft, subItemPaddingTopAndBottom, 0, subItemPaddingTopAndBottom);
            itemTextView.setTextColor(0x88000000);
            itemTextView.setLayoutParams(
                    new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemTextView) {
            };
    }
    return null;
}

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Item item = data.get(position);
    switch (item.type) {
        case HEADER:
            final ListHeaderViewHolder itemController = (ListHeaderViewHolder) holder;
            itemController.refferalItem = item;
            itemController.header_title.setText(item.text);
            if (item.invisibleChildren == null) {
                itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_minus);
            } else {
                itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_plus);
            }
            itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (item.invisibleChildren == null) {
                        item.invisibleChildren = new ArrayList<Item>();
                        int count = 0;
                        int pos = data.indexOf(itemController.refferalItem);
                        while (data.size() > pos + 1 && data.get(pos + 1).type == CHILD) {
                            item.invisibleChildren.add(data.remove(pos + 1));
                            count++;
                        }
                        notifyItemRangeRemoved(pos + 1, count);
                        itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_plus);
                    } else {
                        int pos = data.indexOf(itemController.refferalItem);
                        int index = pos + 1;
                        for (Item i : item.invisibleChildren) {
                            data.add(index, i);
                            index++;
                        }
                        notifyItemRangeInserted(pos + 1, index - pos - 1);
                        itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_minus);
                        item.invisibleChildren = null;
                    }
                }
            });
            break;
        case CHILD:
            TextView itemTextView = (TextView) holder.itemView;
            itemTextView.setText(data.get(position).text);
            break;
    }
    final Item model = data.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(v.getContext());
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

            // Set up the input_desc
            final EditText input_desc = new EditText(v.getContext());
            final EditText input_qty = new EditText(v.getContext());

            // Specify the type of input_desc expected; this, for example, sets the input_desc as a password, and will mask the text
            input_desc.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            input_desc.setHint(R.string.input_hint);

            input_qty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            input_qty.setHint(R.string.input_qty);


            layout.addView(input_desc, layoutParams);
            layout.addView(input_qty, layoutParams);

            try {
                if (!model.getProductDetailObject().getP_name().equals(null)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    builder.setMessage(model.getProductDetailObject().getP_name())
                            .setView(layout)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.submit, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                                    String m_Text_input_desc = input_desc.getText().toString();
                                    String qnty_int_string = input_qty.getText().toString();

                                    int m_Text_input_qty = 0;

                                    if (qnty_int_string != null &&  !qnty_int_string.trim().isEmpty()  ) {
                                        m_Text_input_qty = Integer.parseInt(qnty_int_string);
                                    }



                                    if (!getValidation(m_Text_input_desc, m_Text_input_qty, input_desc)) {
                                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Enter valid desc",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        return;
                                    }


                                    new AddCartItems().setCartItems(model.getProductDetailObject().getP_name(),
                                            m_Text_input_desc, m_Text_input_qty, false);

                                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Desc : " + m_Text_input_desc + " Quanity : " + m_Text_input_qty,
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    //do something
                    builder.show();
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Select Product", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        }
    });
}

private boolean getValidation(String input_name, int input_qnty, EditText input_desc) {
    boolean valid = true;

    if (input_name.isEmpty() || input_name.length() < 3) {
        input_desc.setError("at least 3 characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        input_desc.setError(null);
    }
    return valid;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return data.get(position).type;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

private static class ListHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView header_title;
    public ImageView btn_expand_toggle;
    public Item refferalItem;

    public ListHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        header_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
        btn_expand_toggle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand_toggle);
    }
}

public static class Item {
    public int type;
    public String text;
    public List<Item> invisibleChildren;
    private ProductDetailObject mText;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(int type, String text, ProductDetailObject txt) {
        this.type = type;
        this.text = text;
        this.mText = txt;

    }

    public ProductDetailObject getProductDetailObject() {

        return mText;
    }
}
}
```

At the moment I have created a try-catch block to cater for the Null-pointer which is generated when you click on the text. The Null-Pointer is catched by a toast "Select Product".Please help to make both the text and the circled symbols to populate the child elements.

Here is the stack trace:

```
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.vhg.empire.merchant, PID: 9303
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.vhg.empire.merchant.Account.ExpandableListAdapter$3.onClick(ExpandableListAdapter.java:138)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-30 13:52:19.580 9303-9303/com.vhg.empire.merchant E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

The ExpandandableListAdapter.java is the one above and line 138 is the following line: if (!model.getProductDetailObject().getP_name().equals(null)) {

Comment: The click listener you try-catched is fired for both HEADER and CHILD rows. Something you are doing inside the try clause does not apply to header rows. You can post the stack trace and we'll see the problematic line.

Comment: If I remove the try catch it will give me a NPE

Comment: You keep the catch if you wish for now, but log the stack trace on the catch in addition to the toast. And please post the stack trace in the question so that we can help you.

Comment: I added the stack trace